# About Rsform submission

Tags: joomla-3.x, rsform

I have a claim form built with RSform used in local network.
The users who write the complaints are the users of the joomla site(for exemple user1 user2 user3).
The form contains : the details of the claim (textbox), the date (calender) and the recipient (checkbox) for exemple : Manager, Technical department ...
the recipient also is a user of the joomla site.
=> so for exemple user1 write a complaint to user2.

After the sending of the form(user1 send the complaint),user1 and user2 and user3 can consult the list of complaints through the link RSForm! Pro » Submissions - Directory //or RSForm! Pro » Submissions - View

In this list, i want that only user3 can make modification, so he can add new data to the form (for exemple user3 is the manager and he can say "ok" in a new field dont exist in the original form so i can use a hidden field)

at this moment, user1 can confirm his request by clicking on one button "confirmation".

Comment: Sorry, I'm finding your question a little too Unclear / Too Broad.  So far, I only see your work requirements, but this community is not AirTasker.  What have you tried so far?  Please improve your question and title.

Comment: Thank you.  1) I have a claim form -> 2) after sending to the concerned users -> 
3) all users can see the list of claims through the link RSForm! Pro » Submissions - Directory or RSForm! Pro » Submissions - View -> 4) One of thems only can add more informations in new fields -> 5)
the applicant who send the form can confirm the request after reading the 
information written by the user.

Comment: Please [Edit](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/posts/25115/edit) your question so that all information related to your question can be found in your question.  Then you can delete all of your comments that provide details.  This site is not a forum and must not read "chronologically" like a "forum thread". The full story needs to be in the question.  Please take the [tour].

Comment: I rewrote my question

Answer (score 1):

RSForms has pretty good documentation.  It sounds like you want conditional form fields.  I would suggest having the first field be a select box with choices like

- User 1
- User 2
- User 3

Then you can setup conditional fields to show the subsequent fields only when your select field = User 1 or whatnot. Note that these other fields should not have a field type of "hidden field" as those will never be visible to user. Please take a look at these.
https://www.rsjoomla.com/support/documentation/rsform-pro/frequently-asked-questions/conditional-fields-feature-first-hand-example.html
https://www.rsjoomla.com/support/documentation/rsform-pro/frequently-asked-questions/set-up-conditionals-for-groups-of-fields.html

Or you can write a custom validation if you want:
https://www.rsjoomla.com/support/documentation/rsform-pro/customizing-rsform-pro/custom-validation-rules.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but i need to add more data in RSForm! Pro » Submissions - View or RSForm! Pro » Submissions - Directory .  not in the original form.

Comment: Do you have the directory set to where users can edit their own?  Please update your original question with some more details

Comment: no i dont have because I can't configure it . i add more details : 1) I have a claim form -> 2) after sending to the concerned users -> 3) all users can see the list of claims through the link RSForm! Pro » Submissions - Directory or RSForm! Pro » Submissions - View -> 4) One of thems only can add more informations in new fields -> 5) the applicant who send the form can confirm the request after reading the information written by the user.

Comment: Can you clarify on how you are defining user?  Is it #2 are customers with claim and #3 are the claims officers (or whatever)? #5 is the customer with claim is confirming information written by claims officer?  Please edit the original question with your 1-5, with the users defined better

Comment: it's done... I rewrote my question

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:
Add fields but "hide" them on the form (field = unpublished)
That way the fields are there in the system, just not visible on the front-end form

Comment: Thank you for attempting to support the OP, but asking questions of the OP must not be done as an answer.  Perhaps rephrase your answer so that it doesn't seek a response from the OP.  State your suggestion as a definitive, resolving action.  I will curb my initial urge to delete this post, please edit.